# UIScrollView with UIViews not shown

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

I'm trying to use a UIScrollView with UIViews (to manage them as xib files), for now I have an array where I store the views.

testingView is a `UIViewcontroller` with his own xib file and testingView2 is also an `UIViewcontroller` with his own different xib file

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

_testingView = [[TestingViewController alloc] init];
_testingView2 = [[TestingViewController2 alloc] init];

self.array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: _testingView.view, _testingView2.view, nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollingView.frame.size.width*i;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollingView.frame.size;

[self.scrollingView addSubView: [self.array objectAtIndex:i]];

}

self.scrollingView.contentSize = CGSizeMake (_scrollingView.frame.size.width*[array count], _scrollingView.frame.size.height);

}
```

the problem is that he is taking only the first view (even if I switch them) and the second view is not shown, the same with UIImages instead of views is working, can someone explain me why? seems like he is not seeing the second view in the array order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calculating the variable "frame" inside the for loop when you are not using it?

In my view you should make the following change to your code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollingView.frame.size.width*i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollingView.frame.size;

    **UIView *v=[self.array objectAtIndex:i];**

   **v.frame=frame;**


  **[self.scrollingView addSubView:v];**
```

}

Hope it works.

Comment: yes you're right, that was a residue of what I was trying to do, even if verbumdei is right about that, and I had to do some changes to make it works, your approach is clearly more correct about fixing my problem, so thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop, you calculate frame for newly added subview, but you don't set that frame to that subview.

In your loop, add your subview like this for example:

```
UIView *subview = (UIView *)[array objectAtIndex:i];
subview.frame = frame;
[self.scrollingView addSubView:subview];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the frame for each of the subviews in the scrolling view. For example, you can set the frame of _testingView2.view to be the offset of x from the _testingView1.view frame width.

```
_testingView2.view.frame = CGRectOffset(_testingView2.frame, CGRectGetWidth(_testingView1.frame), 0)
```

There are many ways to calculate the frame. Try to use the methods CGRectWidth, CGRectGetMaxX, etc.